# Error al importar base de datos en phpmyadmin codigo de error #1064

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Buenas tardes compañeros, tengo un problema al tratar de importar una base de datos de sql en phpmyadmin, estoy recibiendo el siguiente error.

Consulta SQL:

> $$$$
>
> MySQL ha dicho: 
>   `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '$' at line 1`

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `ceinarcom_db`
--

DELIMITER $$
--
-- Procedimientos
--
$$

$$

$$

$$

$$

$$

$$

$$

$$

$$

$$

$$

$$

DELIMITER ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `acreditacion`
--
```

Comment: Hola Fernando Lopez Ocampo, bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: error de sintáxis, necesitamos revisar la parte de tu código donde se muestra ese símbolo para ver que esta mal

Comment: de donde es originaria la bbdd, de otro mysql? por lo que parece, no esta bien exportado (los $$ parecen referir a procedimientos almacenados). Es posible que si los eliminas importe bien la bbdd, pero habras perdido la funcionalidad de procedimientos almacenados.

Comment: viene de un backup de otro hosting realizado por la persona de sistemas de la empresa que tenia el hosting.